# What's the best way to return variables from a syncExec?

Tags: java, multithreading, swt

In my SWT Java app I often want to return information from inside a Display.syncExec() call.  The best way I've found so far to do this is:

```
final ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
GUI.display().syncExec(new Runnable(){ public void run() {
   MessageBox mb = /* ... */;
    /* set up messagebox */
   result.add(mb.open());
}});
if (SWT.OK == result.get(0)) { /* ... */ }
```

I think this is allowed because ArrayList is thread-safe, but is there a better container I should be using, or an easier way altogether?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ArrayList` is not thread-safe](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). You can obtain a thread-safe `List` with [`Collections.synchronizedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29). However, it is much simpler to use an `AtomicInteger` in your case or `AtomicReference` in a more general case.

```
final AtomicInteger resultAtomicInteger = new AtomicInteger();
Display.getCurrent().syncExec(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
        MessageBox mb = /* ... */;
            /* set up messagebox */
        resultAtomicInteger.set(mb.open());
}});
if (SWT.OK == resultAtomicInteger.get()) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 3):

I just tackled this problem and my first try was similar - array or list of desired type items. But after a while I made up something like this:

```
abstract class MyRunnable<T> implements Runnable{
    T result;
}
MyRunnable<Integer> runBlock = new MyRunnable<Integer>(){
   MessageBox mb = /* ... */;
    /* set up messagebox */
   result = mb.open();
}
GUI.display().syncExec(runBlock);
runBlock.result; //holds a result Integer
```

It's much tidier and removes redundant variables.

BTW. My really first try was to use UIThreadRunnable, but I didn't want SWTBot dependency, so I dropped this solution. After I made my own solution I found out, they use similar work around in there.

Comment: You should use Callable. It's like Runnable, but allows a return. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList is *not* thread-safe. From the relevant [Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> Note that this implementation is not
>   synchronized. If multiple threads
>   access an ArrayList instance
>   concurrently, and at least one of the
>   threads modifies the list
>   structurally, it must be synchronized
>   externally.

If you need a thread-safe implementation of List, there are (at least) two provided in the JDK: CopyOnWriteArrayList and Vector.

Comment: You're right, but it doesn't actually matter in this case because .syncExec blocks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an Integer[1] array to make it more concise but I don't think it can directly update a non-final variable from inside an anonymous inner class.

```
final Integer[] result = new Integer[1];
```

I thought that you had to declare results as final (but that change wouldn't affect your code).  Since the current Thread blocks until the inner Thread is finished I don't think you need to worry about synchronization (but you might need to make the variable violate so that you see the result).

Comment: IMO this is the best solution (in other words, it's what I did)

Answer (score 1):

If this happens often, you better use subscribe/notify model between your process and view. Your view subscribes to the event which should trigger that message box and gets notified when conditions met.